# .htaccess not allow mobile devices to play .mp3

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, mp3

I have mp3 player, I need to make that player work (and player work now), but in case if someone tried to access mp3 or ogg files in my server/folder, to deny it for all direct (download) access.

How to do it?

I tried this code, all is ok, but it not works for mobile phones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3|ogg)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

What is wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Strange. .htaccess is executed on server side...different client shouldn't make any change... You don't have different domain (sub-domain) for mobile site, right?

Comment: @MilanG I am think no, but I am not sure, anyway, how to change it to work with all my sub-domains ? %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(*\.)?mydomain\.com/ [NC] is that correct? Also, when I tried it, again it not works with this code change.

Comment: Nobody can help with this?